# Prevent BlackBerry Bold from auto zooming in the page?

Tags: mobile, blackberry, zooming

[Please check the page](http://bit.ly/PKMefU).

When opening the page, BlackBerry Bold automatically zooms in the page. While the situation is fine on iPhone.

I had tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1020">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

but BlackBerry Bold still automatically zooms in the page.

BlackBerry Bold is supposed to act like how iPhone does. Is there a workround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying the height and the width?  Some thing like this,

Thanks

Naveen M

Comment: Sorry @Naveenan, but the code isn't visible. Could you type it again?